# Uploaded files are getting deleted in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, content-management-system

I have to administer a Drupal Website, which I didn't set up and honestly, I haven't much experience with Drupal yet.

But I have a serious problem: If I upload a file (it's a PDF) not attached to a node, it will be deleted every few hours. Apparently, I need to indicate it as permanent manually from the file overview page.

Is there a way to set it as permanent automatically?

Hope you can help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the status parameter on the file object then use file_save to save it:

```
// First obtain a file object, for example by file_load...
$file = file_load(10);

// Or as another example, the result of a file_save_upload...
$file = file_save_upload('upload', array(), 'public://', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

// Now you can set the status
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;

// And save the status.
file_save($file);
```